# Teradata: Query the next lowest value of two columns for a given input

Tags: sql, teradata

I have the following two tables:

```
       TableA:
+---------+--------+
|  name   | nm_key |
+---------+--------+
| Bob     |   1124 |
| Sally   |   3278 |
| Frank   |   6484 |
| Mary    |   1125 |
| Annette |   2798 |
+---------+--------+

             TableB:
 +--------+----------+--------+
 | nm_key | sequence | status |
 +--------+----------+--------+
 |   1124 |    33333 |      3 |
 |   2798 |    11111 |      1 |
 |   3278 |    12226 |      2 |
 |   1125 |    24356 |      3 |
 |   6484 |    12272 |      2 |
 +--------+----------+--------+
```

Using the two tables, how do I write a Teradata SQL query that will return the name that has the next lowest status and the next lowest sequence for a name input? For example, an input of Bob will return Frank because the next lowest status is 2 with the next lowest sequence of 12272.

Comment: Lower status than Bob *and* lower sequence than Bob? Or the highest sequence within the lower status? What if you search for Annette, there's no lower status?

Comment: The result should be lower status than Bob and lower sequence than Bob. Both Bob and Mary would return Frank, and both Sally and Frank would return Annette. Annette should return null since there is no lower status.

Answer (score 0):

Let's just focus on `num_key` here and table `b`.  The name comes from joining the results.  One method is a correlated subquery.  The following gets the key

```
select b.*,
       (select top 1 b2.nm_key
        from b b2
        where b2.status < b.status
        order by b2.status desc, b2.sequence desc
       ) as prev_nm_key
from b;
```

Limiting to "Bob" and getting the name are minor adjustments to the logic.

EDIT:

That is a painful limitation.  Here is one workaround:

```
select bb.*, b.nm_key
from (select b.*,
             (select max(b2.status || ':' || b2.sequence) as statseq
              from b b2
              where b2.status < b.status
              order by b2.status desc, b2.sequence desc
             ) as prev_nm_key
      from b
     ) bb join
     b
     on (b.status || ':' || b.sequence) = bb.statseq;
```

Comment: This is my issue with this query: SELECT Failed. 6916:  TOP N Syntax error: Top N option is not supported in subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select * from table1 
Left join table2 on table2.nm_key=table1.nm_key
Where status=ceil(status +.99)
```